# Almost there with jQuery Autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete

At https://jsfiddle.net/Lyfwjrz0/3/ it seemed to be able to take the 12000+ airport names.

```
{label: "04G - Lansdowne Airport", value: "04G"},
{label: "06A - Moton Field Municipal Airport", value: "06A"},
{label: "06C - Schaumburg Regional", value: "06C"},
{label: "06N - Randall Airport", value: "06N"},
```

There are just a few issues:

- It seems to be very slow when the user types the first character. I only ever want the first 7 results dropped-down so is there a way to limit it to 7? I'm wondering if that will fix the slowness issue?
- The bolding of the search characters doesn't seem to work correctly all the time. e.g. type 'lon' and it bolds 'lona' in Barcelona

TIA for any help
Mark

Comment: the fiddle you linked has grocery items not airports...

Comment: @JordanHendrix Apologies - jsfiddle URL now corrected: jsfiddle.net/Lyfwjrz0/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/yaz2mhLy/7/ uses minLength as user DSN mentioned and also displays bold text.

```
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [{
    label: 'honey',
    value: 1
  }, {
    label: 'apples',
    value: 2
  }, {
    label: 'milk',
    value: 3
  }, {
    label: 'tea',
    value: 4
  }, {
    label: 'oranges',
    value: 5
  }, {
    label: 'bread',
    value: 6
  }, {
    label: 'cheese',
    value: 7
  }, {
    label: 'apple-sauce',
    value: 8
  }, {
    label: 'cream-cheese',
    value: 9
  }];
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple things that might help your performance. From http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/:

- delay - set to 500 (miliseconds) so that the search doesn't fire immediately on every key press.
- minLength: implementations you'll find in the wild (Facebook comes to mind) don't offer suggestions until you've typed in 3 characters.

As for "lon" bolding "lona", it's a bug on this line:

```
newLabel+= (i>= startIndex && i <= endIndex) ? "<b>"+arr[i]+"</b>": arr[i];
```

should be

```
newLabel+= (i>= startIndex && i < endIndex) ? "<b>"+arr[i]+"</b>": arr[i];
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried changing that newLabel line you showed at https://jsfiddle.net/Lyfwjrz0/3/. A few things: 
1) When typing in LAX, it bolds correctly for some but it only highlighted the 'LA' for the Los Angeles entry. 2) I set minLength=3 as you recommended. It works great until I enter a comma to begin entering another Airport code in the text box (it's a multi-entry comma separated textbox) e.g. LAX, 3) If someone enters 'Air' it takes a long time as most or many entries have Airport in them. Is there any way to limit the results to say 10 so that it speeds it up for when a user does that?

Comment: I think I may have fixed point 2) above, minLength, at https://jsfiddle.net/Lyfwjrz0/5/ by using:  search: function() {
        // custom minLength
        var term = extractLast( this.value );
        if ( term.length < 3 ) {
            return false;
        }
    }, so just looking to find out how to fix 1) and 3) above

Comment: A couple things I spotted looking at the code again. Where you declare startIndex, you may want to consider calling `.toLowerCase()` on both `item.label` and `$("#tags").val()` so that your comparison is case-insensitive.  
  
I'm not at a place now, and won't be until next week, where I can look at this more closely but I would think having `var maxMatches = 10` and a `var matchesFound = 0` globals, then just check before adding another match to the label, should achieve what you're looking to do.

Comment: Thanks. That would be helpful. I haven't done so much Javascript coding in the past -- just mainly vb.net.